# Firefox Developer Edition (63) no longer shows css rules when inspecting elements in responsive mode

Tags: responsive, developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I've tested this on numerous websites: After switching to responsive mode I can no longer view the CSS rules for an element I select/inspect on the page. This used to work in the past. I've even reset my Firefox to be sure it's not a plugin or some installation issue. Can anyone confirm this or experience this as well? Any suggestions? Is it a bug?

[image]